# Update Bounding Box in OpenGL libGDX

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I currently have a few objects rotating around my 3D world. Each of them have a `BoundingBox` object associated with them. How do I update the bounding box values after calls to `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()`?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to loop over every vertex, calculate it's position in the world (multiply by modelview) and find minimum / maximum vertex coordinates within every object (just like when you compute it for the first time).

Comment: I assume I need to keep track of the current matrix myself? At that point applying the rotations and translations to the bounding box should be relatively simple I hope. Is there a better way to do this? I feel as though this type of thing would be common in almost every game out there.